# Export VisualVM application configuration, then importing

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm

I am moving from VisualVM 1.3.2 to 1.3.3 and want to move all of the remote servers and applications I have setup to this new installation.

I have looked at %HOMEPATH%\Application Data.visualvm\1.3.2 and see configuration for modules and preferences but nothing to do with the applications I have setup.

Please help as I have over 150 servers configured I need to move.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See copy of email below for explanation how to move your configuration from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3:

The defined remote hosts & JMX connections are stored in VisualVM userdir in directory 'repository'. The VisualVM userdir location is displayed in the Help | About | Details dialog. Copying the 'repository' from VisualVM 1.3.2 userdir to VisualVM 1.3.3 userdir will do the trick.